# How to apply the patch for fully hashed menezes-qu-vanstone (fhmqv) to crypto++ that has been installed from the Ubuntu repository

Tags: linux, ubuntu, patch, crypto++, elliptic-curve

I want to use Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) key exchange protocol for a key agreement process. It is already implemented in crypto++ library and I wanted to utilize it. I have already installed crypto++ (by typing sudo apt-get... command in a terminal) but since traditional ECDH is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attack.

I want to use fully hashed menezes-qu-vanstone protocol. Although it is implemented for crypto++ it is not in the main stream so I need to patch it. There is an explanation [here](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Fully_Hashed_Menezes-Qu-Vanstone) but it is for those who built the library from the source code.

Is there anyone who knows how to apply this patch to crypto++ that has been installed from Ubuntu repository? I am using Ubuntu 15.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related sites, either http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but since traditional ECDH is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attack.

What others often do is to pair ECDH with a signature scheme. For example, TLS uses ECDH with a scheme like RSA or ECDSA.

I'm not saying you should do it; I'm only letting you know what others are doing.

---

> it is not in the main stream so I need to patch it...

We will be adding HMQV and FHMQV at the next release. The next release will be happening in the next couple of months.

---

> Is there anyone who knows how to apply this patch to crypto++ that has been installed from Ubuntu repository?

The easiest thing to do would be to probably be to build a new version of the library, and then install it into `/usr/local`. I presume you know how to download and patch. To build and install:

```
# Crypto++ build directory
...
make static dynamic cryptest.exe
sudo make install PREFIX=/usr/local
```

---

You *might* be able to patch Ubuntu version because FHMQV is mostly a header-only implementation. However, `cryptest.exe` will *not* have the validation stuff included. You really need to build the library for it.

Download the patch and perform the following. `fhmqv.h` is the "meat and potatoes" of the patch.

```
sudo cp fhmqv.h /usr/include/cryptopp
```

You also need to add the following to `eccrypto.h`. Start by opening the file with privileges (i.e., `sudo emacs /usr/include/cryptopp/eccrypto.h`).

Then, add this to the top of `eccrypto.h`:

```
#include "fhmqv.h"
```

And add this to the bottom of `eccrypto.h`:

```
//! Fully Hashed Menezes-Qu-Vanstone in GF(p) with key validation,
/*! <a href="http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/408">A Secure and Efficient Authenticated DiffieHellman Protocol</a>
    Note: this is FHMQV, Protocol 5, from page 11; and not FHMQV-C.
*/
template <class EC, class COFACTOR_OPTION = CPP_TYPENAME DL_GroupParameters_EC<EC>::DefaultCofactorOption, class HASH = SHA256>
struct FHMQV
{
    typedef FHMQV_Domain<DL_GroupParameters_EC<EC>, COFACTOR_OPTION, HASH> Domain;
};
```

Most of the other stuff in the DIFF file is not needed, like the changes to `wait.h` and `wait.cpp`. It was added to address outstanding bugs. The bugs were cleared at Crypto++ 5.6.3.